# Gremlin query: how to add multiple edges that contain aggregated information?

Tags: gremlin

My graph contains some "Person" nodes that "ContributedTo" some "Conversations" nodes. I want to write a Gremlin query that will create "TalksWith" edges directly between "Person" nodes. That edge should contain a property "countConversations" that shows how many conversations both these persons contributed to.

Is this possible doing using one Gremlin query for all "Person" nodes at once?

Here's my graph setup (using Gremlin console):

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
g.addV("Person").as("p1").
addV("Person").as("p2").
addV("Person").as("p3").
addV("Person").as("p4").
addV("Person").as("p5").
addV("Conversation").as("c1").
addV("Conversation").as("c2").
addV("Conversation").as("c3").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p1").to("c1").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p2").to("c1").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p3").to("c1").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p1").to("c2").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p2").to("c2").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p3").to("c2").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p4").to("c2").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p5").to("c2").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p1").to("c3").
addE("ContributedTo").from("p3").to("c2")
```

What I want doing is creating "TalkedWith" edges like this

```
addE("TalkedWith").from("p1").to("p2").property("countConversations",2)
```

I wrote a query to count how many conversations a specific person had with other persons

```
g.V(0L).out("ContributedTo").in("ContributedTo")
.hasId(without(0L)).groupCount().order(local).by(values,desc).next()
```

Now I want to run this calculation for each person and create "TalksWith" edges.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it:

```
gremlin> g.V(0L).hasLabel('Person').
......1>   store('p').
......2>   out('ContributedTo').
......3>   in('ContributedTo').
......4>   where(without('p')).
......5>   groupCount().
......6>   unfold().
......7>   addE('TalkedWith').from(select('p').unfold()).to(select(keys)).
......8>     property('countConversations',select(values))
==>e[18][0-TalkedWith->1]
==>e[19][0-TalkedWith->2]
==>e[20][0-TalkedWith->3]
==>e[21][0-TalkedWith->4]
gremlin> g.E().hasLabel('TalkedWith').valueMap()
==>[countConversations:2]
==>[countConversations:3]
==>[countConversations:1]
==>[countConversations:1]
```

Given what you provided in your question as your progress in writing this traversal I'll assume you follow everything up to the `groupCount()` at line 5. At that point, we have a `Map` of the people `v[0]` talked to and the number of times they spoke. The next line deconstructs that `Map` into its component entries and iterates them creating an edge for each with `addE()`. The `from` vertex is gathered from "p" where it was original stored in a `List` and the `to` is extracted from the current key in the count map. The "countConversations" property then gets its value from current value of the count map.